# Docker compose - mount error while starting container

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, filesystems

I am running macOS: 13.3.1 (22E261)

This is a `apache.Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.2-apache-bullseye

RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    zip \
    procps \
    locales \
    libpq-dev \
    lsb-release \
    libicu-dev \
    iproute2 \
    unzip \
    iputils-ping && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pgsql pdo_pgsql && \
    mkdir /tmp/host/

COPY ./vhosts/*.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
RUN cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/ && a2ensite * && \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    apachectl configtest && \
    service apache2 restart

USER root
```

And this `docker-compose.yaml` configuration file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  apache_php8.2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apache.Dockerfile
    container_name: ${APACHE_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - target: 80 # the port inside the container
        published: 81 # the publicly exposed port
        protocol: tcp # the port protocol (tcp or udp)
        mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - local_docker_network
    volumes:
      - ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/
      - ${HOST_TRANSFER_DIRECTORY}:/tmp/host/
networks:
  local_docker_network:
    driver: bridge
```

And `.env`:

```
APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT="/Users/jirka/Sites/"
HOST_TRANSFER_DIRECTORY="/Users/jirka/tmp/"
APACHE_CONTAINER_NAME="apache_php8.2"
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME="localdev"
```

And I get an error while running the container, I read many SO Q/A, but none of this (e.g. restart Docker daemon) helped me.

> $ docker container start 5d4ae59ee339
>
> Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path
> '/host_mnt/Users/jirka/tmp': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/jirka: operation
> not permitted Error: failed to start containers: 5d4ae59ee339

Comment: It looks like a problem with either `${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}` or `${HOST_TRANSFER_DIRECTORY}`. What are they defined as in your `.env` file?

Comment: @HansKilian I added `.env` setting, thank you.

Comment: Do those directory names make sense to you? Do they exist? If they don't exist, then try creating them.

Comment: Yes, all directories are completely fine.